# how to store array string in json in launchsetting.json file in .net

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to store multiple date formats in the launchsetting.json file. but while im storing in the launch setting its giving compilation error - "value must be one of the types:string".
how to store multiple values in the key.

```
"Date_Formats":["dd/mm/yyyy","yyyy/mm/dd"]

 string[] formats =(string[]).JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(getEnvironmentVariable());
```

Comment: you can specify like `"Date_Formats": "dd/mm/yyyy; yyyy/mm/dd"` and then spilt inside your app.

Comment: I tested local and didn't received any error, might it be your Lint config? maybe if not, then share your error logs

Comment: When debugging,which row will get `"value must be one of the types:string"`,and can you share your `getEnvironmentVariable()`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `lauchSettings.json` for custom configuration is a bad idea. Leave this file only for Visual Studio. For your configs you should use `appsettings.json`.
2. So, if you want to pass Date_Formats in your configuration, you should add this key with values (`"Date_Formats":["dd/mm/yyyy","yyyy/mm/dd"]`) to the `appsettings.json`.
   Then in the code project:

```
public void MyMethod(IConfiguration config) 
{
    var myValue = config.GetValue<string[]>("Date_Formats");
}
```